# Numpy arrays created from pandas dataframe show strange behaviour

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I've a csv file which is having long image vectors. The format of the file is:

```
imgName,-0.947363,0.83463728,0.635252,0.787878.....
```

I need to drop my first column and use rest of the data. When I create my numpy array using numpy library like:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('fewvec.csv', delimiter=',')
data = np.delete(my_data, 0, 1)
data = data.astype(np.float64)
```

everything works well. When I create my nparray using pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv("fewvec.csv", header=None)
data1 = df.iloc[:, 1:].values
```

the created data1 array looks exactly same to me as data array created above. But when I pass this to a library(nmslib) it generates wrong answer using data1 array. Is there any fundamental difference between these two arrays?

Comment: Yes? You're skipping a column.

Comment: I need to skip the first column because it has image names. I'm doing that in both code snippets. The shape of data and data1 is same so I don't think that might be a problem.

Comment: Have you checked if the arrays are really identical?